# How to calculate the average current

Tags: voltage, amperage, atx

I have an ATX which the yellow wire is "+ 12 v ,18 amp" and "blue is -12v , 1 amp". When I use them together I got 24 v but I am confused how to calculate the max ampere. How to calculate the max amp?

Comment: What do you use these voltages for?

Comment: The +12V and the -12V winding are in series, and they share the same ground. The max current you can draw is the minimum of these two: 1A. Note: In most of the ATX PSUs the -12V output is taken from a linear regulator like 7912.

Comment: @Peter Mp 1 now I am using them for electrolysis which needs about 0.5 amp

Comment: @Rohat Kilic so my max amp will be 1 amp

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu yes.